# Is there a way to annotate Python source code with the profiler results?

Tags: python, profiler

I'm currently using [cProfile and pstats](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) to profile some Python code.

Is there a way to annotate the source code with the time taken on each line? Ideally this would be a coloured (HTML) version of the source with expensive lines highlighted in red or something.

Comment: If you just want to find the most expensive lines, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, look at [line profiler](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/) or [profilehooks](http://mg.pov.lt/profilehooks/)

I think is so simple to render the output to html, with your own codes.

and for graph, take a look at [gprof2dot](http://gprof2dot.jrfonseca.googlecode.com/hg/gprof2dot.py)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you ask for but might be helpful:

http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot

It draws a graph which makes it really easy to see which functions take up your execution time.

I'm not aware of a python profiler that tracks execution line by line. I suspect that doing so would confuse the results because it would be too much overhead.